# Bias type based on achievement of goals

Tags: logic

What type of bias is it if I favour an idea because the implementation of the idea will benefit me? Example: I favour limited gun control despite reading contrary arguments because my livelihood is dependent on the sale of guns. Related to confirmation bias but I think is slightly different in that the outcome is directly related to my perceived well-being.

Comment: This is not a type of bias, it is a type of biases' cause. It is called [vested interest](https://sites.google.com/site/flawsinreasoning/bias-and-vested-interest-interpreting-facts-unreasonably), "a particular cause of bias which occurs not simply when one unreasonably favors a preferred perspective, but in fact favors a perspective which provides them with specific benefits. An obvious example of vested interest would be anyone who is paid to promote a product in commercials." And it causes *bias* only when acting subliminally, conscious self-serving is manipulation, not bias.

Comment: All individuals are biased towards protecting their vested interests and we favor ideas to support this bias.